# Center image on another image

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+, autoresize

I am fairly new to C# GDI+ graphics.

I want to draw an image over another, which should be centered horizontally and vertically in a fixed height and width container on an image.

I tried to do this with horizontal centering and the output is weird.

I am sharing the commented code of how I am trying to do it, let me know if there is any easier way to do it, I just want to scale and center the image.

```
//The parent image resolution is 4143x2330 
//the container for child image is 2957x1456
Image childImage = Image.FromFile(path.Text.Trim());
Image ParentImage = (Image)EC_Automation.Properties.Resources.t1;
Bitmap bmp2 = (Bitmap)ParentImage;
Graphics graphic = Graphics.FromImage(ParentImage); 
graphic.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
double posX = (2957 / 2.0d) - (childImage.Width / 2.0d); 
//HAlf of the container size - Half of the image size should make it center in container
graphic.DrawImage((Image)childImage,
new Rectangle(new Point((int)posX, 420), new Size( 2957, 1456))); //Drawing image
```

Comment: its hard to troubleshoot weird, can you be a bit more descriptive on what is occuring???

Comment: `ScaleImage`is what? `graphic ` is what? (created how?) - Also: please try to format the code lines to fit in the code area without scrolling!

Comment: I've tried to reproduce the issue, but this seems to work correctly. Make sure that content You use as images is correctly loaded (both `ParentImage` and `childImage`).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Solved it , I was drawing the image of fixed width, whereas it should have been with a new width based on the aspect ratio and new height,

Also I was taking trying to find the center of the image from Container, which should have been the center of the whole parent Image

Answer (score 13):

```
public Image ScaleImage(Image image, int maxWidth, int maxHeight)
{
    var ratioX = (double)maxWidth / image.Width;
    var ratioY = (double)maxHeight / image.Height;
    var ratio = Math.Min(ratioX, ratioY);

    var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * ratio);
    var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * ratio);

    var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
    {
        // Calculate x and y which center the image
        int y = (maxHeight/2) - newHeight / 2;
        int x = (maxWidth / 2) - newWidth / 2;
        
        // Draw image on x and y with newWidth and newHeight
        graphics.DrawImage(image, x, y, newWidth, newHeight);
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: `var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxWidth);` need to be replaced by
`var newImage = new Bitmap(maxWidth, maxHeight);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Gabriel Calegari

for center image set x below code

```
int x = (PaperWidth/ 2) - imageWidth / 2;
graph.DrawImage(image, x, 0, imageWidth, ImageHeight);
```